# Difference in react between rendering component and calling a function which returns JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can somebody help me figure out what is going on here and why? I've tried googling, but people focus on one way being faster vs other, one being more correct, etc... I didn't find resource which explains what is going on under the hood, what is the actual implementation difference and why do they behave differently.

**I am interested in why it behaves like it does and what triggers that behavior.**

Let's look at this code

```
const SomeComponent = (arg) => {
  const [typedAnswer, setTypedAnswer] = useState();
  const shouldAskForUserInput= arg === 1; // assume true
  const handleInputChange = (e) => setTypedAnswer(e.target.value);

  const ShortAnswer = () => (
    <Input type="text"
           name="answer"
           value={typedAnswer}
           autofocus
           handleInputChange={handleInputChange} />
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>whatever</p>
      <p>something else</p>
      {shouldAskForUserInput && <ShortAnswer />}
    </div>
  )
```

In this example, it will render a `div` with 2 `p` and an `input` field. This input field, when typed into behaves like any normal controlled component, except it doesn't.

If you type `test` into this input field and then move your cursor in the middle and try typing numbers `12` you will end up with string `te1st2`. This is because after each keypress (`onChange`) it will render again the input field. If I remove `autofocus` from input, you can type only one character at the time.

If I change following so that it is function call instead

```
  return (
    <div>
      <p>whatever</p>
      <p>something else</p>
      {shouldAskForUserInput && ShortAnswer()}
    </div>
  )
```

It will start to behave as expected, I can type any number of characters inside the input, it doesn't rerender on change, etc. Same result if I remove the function all together and put the input code directly instead of function call.

Now, what is actually happening there and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go! The article doesn't go into React.createComponent() as much but I think it's a good jumping-off point.

https://dev.to/igor_bykov/react-calling-functional-components-as-functions-1d3l

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Comment: Every React dev should read the dev.to article!

Comment: Yes, it is the same issue and it also does go into detail of why and how. Just moving the declaration of `ShortAnswer` outside of the  `SomeComponent` fixes the issue and it can be mounted as component and it behaves as expected.